# MSAL In-Memory cache for App Based Tokens

Tags: azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL and want to enable In-Memory caching.
The article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnetcore#application-flows-acquiretokenforclient-acquiretokenformanagedidentity
states that **Only access tokens are cached. One token about 2-3KB when persisted. There will be 1 token per app client ID * tenants * downstream resources. For example, a multi-tenanted app serving 1000 tenants and needing tokens for Graph and SharePoint will use: 3KB * 1000 * 2 i.e. approximately 6 MB**.

The above approximate token size with Graph and SharePoint as examples of 2 resources. Now sharepoint as an example can have multiple sites within a tenant and would actually mean a different resource url for each sharepoint site. So can we say there will be 1 Token for client + tenant + graph resource, but multiple tokens for sharepoint for the same tenant in the cache?